# Completion Command Handler

Tags: c#, intellisense, completionhandler

I was trying out the "Displaying Statement Completion Walkthrough" on MSDN but am unable to build it without error.

On the site they asked to build **TestCompletionCommandHandler class**. Under Implementing The Completion Command Handler Provider.

However on Implementing the Completion Command Handler. It asked to create another classname by the same name, **TestCompletionCommandHandler class**.

Question.

1. Which is the correct class name?

Thank you

Comment: I did not see that on the site. Read more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cite from the site (I hope you are talking about)

[Walkthrough: Displaying Statement Completion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx)

> ## Implementing the Completion Command Handler Provider
>
> ### To implement the completion command handler provider
>
> 1. Add a file named **TestCompletionCommandHandler**.
> 2. Add a class named **TestCompletionHandlerProvider** that implements `IVsTextViewCreationListener`.
>
> ## Implementing the Completion Command Handler
>
> ### To implement the completion command handler
>
> 1. Add a class named **TestCompletionCommandHandler** that implements `IOleCommandTarget`:

The instruction is very clear that you should end up with **one file** named **TestCompletionCommandHandler.cs** containing **two classes** and both classes have for sure different names:

```
[Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
[Name("token completion handler")]
[ContentType("plaintext")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
internal class TestCompletionHandlerProvider : IVsTextViewCreationListener
{
    // implementation
}

internal class TestCompletionCommandHandler : IOleCommandTarget
{
   // implementation 
}
```

Comment: thank you for you clarification! I wasn't sure of what they meant, I thought it was two different classes. Cheers! :)